# "There is already an open datareader associated with this command" - even when using Include()

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am trying to load all the `Dish` objects. `Dish` and `DishImage`s have a one-to-many relationship i.e. a `Dish` can have many `DishImage`s associated with it.

Here is the code for both the classes.

1. [Dish](http://pastebin.com/YDdQ5yA3)
2. [DishImage](http://pastebin.com/bKPXvP1Z)

This is how I am trying to retrieve it in action method:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult TopDishes()
    {
        IEnumerable<Dish> topDishes = dishRepository.Dishes.Include( d => d.DishImages );                                                        
        return PartialView(topDishes);
    }
```

Here is the code for view:

```
  @model IEnumerable<RestaurantHub.Domain.Entities.Dish>

 @foreach (var dish in Model)
 {
    <div class="top-ten-offers-list">

      <div class="top-ten-offer">
        <p class="top-ten-deal-description">
            @dish.Description
        </p>

        <img src="@dish.DishImages.First().ImagePath" />
        <p class="top-ten-deal-title">@dish.Name</p>
     </div>

   </div>
}
```

I have read several SO questions most of them suggest using `Include()` (which I am doing), others suggest setting MARS to true. I believe I'm missing some subtle point here. Any help is appreciated.

**Debug info:**

If I debug the code upto the action method I can verify (by enumerating the results) that correct data is being loaded. But when the control reaches `foreach` loop in the view it throws the mentioned error.

If I remove the line `@dish.DishImages.First().ImagePath` from view it works fine, though I don't get any images.

[image: Debug view of Result Set]

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `.Include()` and `.ToList()` it instead?

Comment: Try using Single() in place of First()  ,But single will throw exception if no result is returned .

Comment: @RowanFreeman Error page says "Sequence contains no elements and entity command execution exception is thrown.

Comment: Why don't you try to send a single image field to your partial view .

Comment: I have to go somewhere for a couple of hours so I will not be able answer immediately. I will try to get back as soon as I can. My apologies.

Comment: @RowanFreeman If I do what you said, the `DishImages` is properply populated. But same thing happens when control reaches the foreach loop in View code.

Comment: @RowanFreeman removing Include() and adding .ToList() resolves the issue, but I am not sure WHY is it so. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you have multiple queries at same time:

... *When Code First creates a connection by
convention, which it has been in our examples, it will enable MARS. If you are supplying
your own connection, you will need to ensure that MARS is enabled if you want to be
able to have multiple active queries.*

*If you don’t enable MARS and your code tries to run two active queries, you will receive
an exception. The exception you receive will depend on the operation that triggers the
second query, but the inner exception will be an InvalidOperationException stating
“There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be
closed first.”* - `from Julia Lerman's Programming EF DbContext`

It seems that you've created your own Connection for EF in the web.config. If so, you should add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` to its `connectionString` property:

```
<add name="..." connectionString="metadata=res:...;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=... ;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True; //Add this
App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**Update:**

In fact, the problem is from your view. the `<img src="@dish.DishImages.First().ImagePath" />` line causes that exception. You ask why?! I'll tell you why:

First of all, you performed a query on your db:

```
IEnumerable<Dish> topDishes = dishRepository.Dishes.Include( d => d.DishImages );                                                        
return PartialView(topDishes);
```

However, in fact you didn't perform any query! you just created an IEnumerable collection (That's because you didn't call `.ToList()`, `.AsEnumerable()`, etc.) and this isn't a problem.

So you pass a collection to your view. The first query performs in your `foreach` loop - OK, still no problem...

Until we get to the `img` tag: `<img src="@dish.DishImages.First().ImagePath" />`. This (`@dish.DishImages.First()`) performs a new query to db --> the problem!

**Solution:**

I don't know that calling `.ToList()` in your controller solve your problem or not - maybe. However your current EF connection string **MUST** have the `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` property to work correctly in these situations.

Comment: I assumed the OP had done this because it was mentioned, but I don't know.

Comment: @AminSaghi I knew that enabling MARS is one way to solve the problem. However, as I mentioned in the comment on @juhan_h's answer `Include()` should also have eliminated the issue since it pre-loads the objects. May be I got it wrong.

Comment: @MohammadYaseen - No, you'e misunderstanding that. Your problem is that you have two separate synchronous queries. I've updated my answer with extra explanation

Comment: @AminSaghi Thanks for the explanation. Removing `Include()` and adding `ToList()` solves the problem. I will do more reading on this part of EF / LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any good reasons why you are using an `IEnumerable` and don't materialize your collection to `List`/`Array`? I think your problem would dissapear, if you would get all the results to memory (`ToList()`/`ToArray()`) and then hand them over to your view where you could manipulate the in-memory collection however you see fit.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I was unable to figure out that why am I getting Open Datareader error even though I am using `Include()`. I thought that it would pre-load (Eagerly) `DishImages` and hence there would be no "queries within a query".